# Efficiently limit number of hits per minute (block web scraping or copy-bots) in PHP

Tags: php, performance, captcha, processing-efficiency

I am faced with the problem of bots copying all the content off my webpage (which I try to update quite often).

I try to ban them, or obfuscate code to make it more difficult to copy. However, they find some way to overcome these limitations.

I'd like to try to limit the number of hits per minute (or X time, not neccesarily minutes), but use a Captcha to overcome those limits. Something like if you've requested more than 10 pages in the last 5 minutes, you need to prove you are human using a Captcha. So, if the user is a legitimate user, you'll be able to continue surfing the web.

I'd like to do it only in the content pages (to do it more efficiently). I had thought of MemCached, but since I don't owe the server, I can't use it. If I were using Servlets I'd use HashMap or similar, but since I use PHP, I am still trying to think of a solution.

I don't see MySql (or databases) as a solution, since I can have many hits per seconds. And I should be deleting after a few minutes old request, creating a lot of unnecesary and non-efficient traffic.

Any ideas?

**A summary:**
*If I get too many hits per minute in a section of the webpage, I'd like to limit it using Captcha efficiently, in PHP. Something like if you've requested more than 10 pages in the last 5 minutes, you need to prove you are human using a Captcha.*

Comment: It can already be a problem to detect that the "same" user is sending "a lot" of requests in a given timeframe. How do you intend to reveal that?

Comment: Just going off my own browsing habits, 10 pages in 5 minutes isn't a lot - using a captcha for people like me will cause a lot of annoyance. Personally, that would put me off, big time

Comment: why not just block them at your firewall or with htaccess?

Comment: The only way this will successfully work, before even implementing the Captcha-idea, is to be able to identify individual users - which will require a login system. Otherwise, you'll have to rely on cookies (easily dropped/spoofed) or annoy one two many people (imagine if multiple people on the same network hit your site - they all have the same IP, so how do you tell them apart?).

Comment: You could use cloudflare to cache your static assets, it'd help lessen your server traffic too

Comment: Johnny, I just did a test and in the last 5 minutes I open 18 pages on Stackoverflow.  I editted 3 posts, voted several times, and this is my second comment.  I believe 10 pages in 5 minutes is too tight a restriction, and you will be blocking regular users.

Comment: The 10 pages in the last 5 minutes was just and example.
Furthermore, I don't mean everypage, only the special content (to have a name). Which makes no sense to open more than 2-3 every hour or so.

.htaccess isn't an option (almost impossible to maintain, and I'd like to be proactive, I don't want to block them once they have the content).

Answer (score 2):

Your questions kind of goes against the spirit of the internet.

1. Everyone copies/borrows from everyone
2. Every search engine has a copy of everything else on the web

I would guess the problem you're having is that these bots are stealing your traffic? If so, I'd suggest you try implementing an API allowing them to use your content legitimately.

This way you can control access, and crucially you can ask for a linkback to your site in return for using your content. This way your site should be number 1 for the content. You don't even really need an API to implement this policy.

If you insist on restricting user access you have the following choices:

1. Use a javascript solution and load the content into the page using Ajax. Even this is not going to fool the best bots.
2. Put all your content behind a username/password system.
3. Block offending IPs - it's a maintenance nightmare and you'll never have a guarantee but it'll probably help.

The problem is - if you want your content to be found by Google AND restricted to other bots you're asking the impossible.

Your best option is create an API and control people copying your stuff rather than trying to prevent it.

Comment: 1.- I don't copy, I create the content myself (my team, which I pay).
2.- I don't mind search engines crawling regular pages, except for those of the valuable content, for those, they'd be crawled except for the real content itself, which is to be displayed when the captcha is entered.

1.- JavaScript isn't an option, tried that, and easy to overcome.
2.- That wouldn't be useful. I don't want regular users to sign up, the page is free to use, unless you misuse it.
3.- I've tried that, but dynamic IPs come here. I can't block several bots everyday, is a pain in the ***.

Comment: I don't want that content to be crawled by Google,
I only want that particular part and content of the web accessible to regular users.

**So..., to sum up.
I just need a technical solution to limit that. Not a lot of people arguing whether I should do it or not.
Which, BTW, I have seen implemented in other websites.**

Comment: The solution I am looking for is **something like this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816057/varnish-cache-with-php-captcha-for-anti-site-scrapping-algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816057/varnish-cache-with-php-captcha-for-anti-site-scrapping-algorithm)

But..., in a shared webserver where I can't install things** like memcached, which would be my ideal solution.


Just to clarify, the problem is that bots copy the content as if it were created by themselves, and it takes me (our team) quite a lot of effort, time and money to create.

Comment: 1) Javascript with Ajax - i.e. fetch the data from the DB only once the user has filled the captcha form will improve but not fix your issues.
2) Fair enough - no username/password system - but if people can view it, they can also copy it.
3) Agreed re: dynamic IPs and bot blocking - it's a pain.

All I'm saying is that if you have bot writers specifically targeting your site, i.e. writing bots for it, you will not be able to block them. As long as content is visible to humans, bots will be able to pretend to be human and grab that content.

Comment: Having said that, if you want a decent captcha, google recaptcha works VERY well and also these image based ones work well - http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin - although be careful to make sure the implementation works on mobiles/tablets.

Comment: Well, I am more looking a solution like this:
http://simonwillison.net/2009/jan/7/ratelimitcache/
But, instead of MemCached, which I can't use, with a different technology. 
A solution using DDBB, as explained in that link, isn't interesting or useful in a real environment.

And what I am looking here is for a technical solution to do exactly so.